# how to handle empty tags using DOM parser in android

Tags: android, parsing, dom

In my xml there can be empty tags like

```
<name/>
```

The problem is that when I parse the xml, I am getting null pointer exception when I reach this line in the xml. Currently I am fetching like this:

```
employees.item(k).getFirstChild().getNodeValue()
```

How should I check tags like this in my parsing file? Please help me out.

Comment: simply put `try & catch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to check `NULL` instead of using `try..catch` block:

```
if(employees.item(k).getFirstChild() != null) {
    employees.item(k).getFirstChild().getNodeValue()
}
```

Just a sample code to answer question, doesn't make it at best performance.

Answer (score 0):

What about checking getFirstChild() result for not being null?
(it's null if there are no children)